# Sony a7 raw files converted to DNG won't open in non-Adobe applications

Tags: raw, sony, dng, adobe-camera-raw, zeiss

I have accidentally converted some of my RAW files into DNG while importing to Lightroom. Normally this is not a problem as most photo applications open DNGs as well. My issue is that whatever photo I have taken with Sony a7 and Sony Zeiss 35mm f/2.8 can't be opened in any application other than Lightroom and Photoshop. Apple Preview can't display their content and they can't be opened in Capture One either. Photos I have taken with third party lenses on the same camera all work seamlessly everywhere (although passed through the same RAW->DNG conversion). Why does this happen and is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Could it be that Lightroom has used a newer process version for the photos you can't open?

Comment: But I have converted the files (with or without Zeiss lens) using the same version of Lightroom, shot and converted in the same day!

Comment: Peculiar indeed. [I saw GIMP can't open long exposure RAW's.] (http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/53218/why-wont-gimp-2-8-open-my-long-exposure-shots) Which is a bug of course.  For trouble shootings sake, have you tried using 'exiftool' to modify the exif of the files and change the lens variable?

Comment: I didn't know that is an option. I will try tonight.

Comment: How do the other apps work with the original RAW files?  If they work fine, I'd skip the conversion to DNG.

Comment: As I said the conversion was accidental. Normally I don't need to convert.

Comment: I'm with Jan. There are different versions of DNG, and the third party applications must not support the latest version yet.

Comment: I don't see that using Lightroom 5.7.1 with my Sony A7ii raw files converted to DNG.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does this happen and is there any way to fix it?

If the 3rd party software does not decode the file it is natural to suggest that it happens because of the author of programs which are able to decode the file and which are used to manipulate the files successfully *flipped* something up that causes an error in 3rd party program.

Report this problem via official Adobe channels.

You may also try finding compiled version of `dng_validate` which is a part of DNG SDK to have additional information. You may try compiling it yourself with Express version of Visual Studio if you have enough knowledge.